# Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Can we say that $M - M = \{ n - m : n,m \in M\}$ is also a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was thinking about this for a while. The definition I use for the smooth manifold is the same as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition). Let $\{(U_k,\phi_k)\}$ is a smooth atlas of $M$. Then the natural atlas which was coming in my mind for $M-M$ was $\{(U_i - U_j, \phi_i - \phi_j)\}$ where $(\phi_i - \phi_j)(u)=\phi_i(u) - \phi_j(u) \; \forall u \; \in U_i - U_j$. Is my approach correct?

By $M - M$ I just mean formal difference of two sets where an element $x$ of $M-M$ can be written as $n-m$ for some $n,m \in M$. Note that "difference" in $M-M$ has no meaning but I am seeking a suitable atlas for this set so that when I am in some $\Bbb R^n$, I will do subtraction as per the addition is done in the group $\Bbb R^n$.

As a beginner in learning the subject, I am not confident in writing down the details. Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** After a recent comment by @MikeMiller, I realized that I was actually working in $M \times M$. So I thought to change my definition of $M - M$. I see now $M - M$ as a set of equivalence classes where the equivalence relation is such that any to pairs $(m,n)$ and $(p,q)$ (or $m-n$ and  $p-q$) are equivalent if we have a suitable atlas for $M-M$ such that in local coordinates, $m-n=p-q \in \Bbb R^n$. The problem is I want to know whether such an atlas exists.

Comment: You can't sum in a general manifold.

Comment: @positrón0802 You mean can't I think a manifold as a set?

Comment: What do you mean by $n-m$ for $n,m\in M$?

Comment: @positrón0802 I just mean formal set difference.

Comment: @positrón0802 So every element of $M-M$ can be written as "difference" of some two elements of $M$. When we are in local coordinates via $\phi_i$'s  will we use difference as per that in $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: The only way I can think to define this in the way you mean is via some embedding into $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some $N$. This is similar to what you want to do, as you can construct an embedding using the charts and a partition of unity.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes. I want to give the meaning of "difference" to the elements once I'm in a suitable $\Bbb R^n$ via suitable atlas. I've defined such an atlas in the post.

Comment: I don't see how your atlas would work exactly. An atlas is not only bijections of the subsets with $\mathbb{R}^n$, but also transition maps to piece them together. How would you define those?

Comment: But there's more than one chart per point.

Comment: A manifold starts its life as a set. What, precisely, is your underlying set? Is it the same as the Cartesian product $M \times M$?

Comment: @Randall But in the maximal atlas, we can have more charts per point right ?

Comment: @MikeMiller I am not sure how cartesian product is relevant here. Perhaps, you are I asking about $M -M$ I suppose. In that case, I am defining it like this : The elements of $M-M$ are just formal differences of elements $M$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I don't want to give meaning to $n-m$ in $M-M$ at all. So if $x$ is any element of $M-M$ I will just say that $x=n-m$ for some $n,m \in M$. But only through atlas, when I am in $\Bbb R^n$ I will do subtraction $\phi_i(n)-\phi_j(m)$. And this subtraction is done via group addition of the group $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: But that just doesn't work. Where the charts overlap, the two different definitions of the subtraction might not agree.

Comment: @MattSamuel Oh, I see. So is there any other way to think about this?

Comment: You could embed the manifold in a vector space then subtract as you please. Like I said, it's similar.

Comment: @Randall Got your point. The way I have defined the atlas, it doesn't work. Can we define some other atlas?

Comment: After this preliminary discussion it seems evident that the question does not have a clear meaning, and so I am voting to close as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: A "formal difference" $m-n$ seems to be no more than a pair of elements $(m,n)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Ah! I didn't think like this. But I will argue it this way: Let's take $M - M$ to be the set of equivalence classes $[(m,n)]$ such that two elements  are equivalent if in $\Bbb R^n$ using local coordinates we get the same difference of both elements in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I have edited my question and now I see $M-M$ as a set of certain equivalence classes.

Comment: If $M$ is path connected and the atlas on $M$ is maximal, it seems like it should be possible to put any two points $p, q$ of $M$ in the same chart (by "gluing" charts along a path), and then, via scaling & rotating, there should exist a chart with $\varphi(p) = 0$ and $\varphi(q) = 1$ -- i.e. it seems to me that your "equivalence class" definition of $M - M$ has only the "same" and "different" classes -- the classes represented by $(p, p)$ and $(p, q)$ for any $p \neq q$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question but I feel it's too long to be included in a comment. I just want to mention that there's an interesting result regarding the Minkowski sum of $2$ convex sets with smooth (of class $C^\infty$) boundary.

[Smoothness of Vector Sums of Plane Convex Sets](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12183/10199?fbclid=IwAR0wOJwQZC3TaQx2Iyrq_FaexZqVJ0tLFy79NeJ66ShJugtIoOvztb-0S_8)

The main result is that the sum of $2$ convex sets with $C^\infty$ need not have $C^\infty$ boundary. In fact we only get the smoothness of the boundary up to 
 class $C^{20/3}$. This might suggest that the answer to your question could be negative (thought I am not sure since your question right now is not well-defined).